# Can't seem to add a panel to a frame, from another class

Tags: java

I've been struggling with this for a while. See my code below. I'm trying to add the HighscorePaneel to the Mainframe. I've made both highscorePaneel, and mainFrame. But the line

```
        mainFrame.add(highscorePaneel);
```

gives an error in eclipse "mainFrame cannot be resolved" and I don't know why.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
package lunarlockout;

public class LunarLockoutApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Mainframe mainFrame = new Mainframe();
    }
}
```

second class ( removed some code that is not needed to post)

```
package lunarlockout;

public class Mainframe extends JFrame   {

    public  Mainframe(){
        setSize(1200, 800);
        setTitle("Lunar Lockout!");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    HoofdmenuPaneel hoofdmenuPaneel = new HoofdmenuPaneel();
    add(hoofdmenuPaneel);

    setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

a third class

```
public class HighscorePaneel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public HighscorePaneel(){

    setLayout(null);
    setSize(330, 528);
    setLocation(461, 137);
    setBackground( new Color(255, 255, 255, 25) );
    setVisible(true);
}
```

and my last class, the one with the error:

```
package lunarlockout;

public class HighscoreInzien {

    Mainframe mainFrame;

public HighscoreInzien(Mainframe mainFrame) {
    this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
}

public void run() {

    HighscorePaneel highscorePaneel = new HighscorePaneel();
    mainFrame.add(highscorePaneel);

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

HoofdmenuPaneel class

```
public class HoofdmenuPaneel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JButton selecteerLevelButton;
private JButton spelHervattenButton;
private JButton highscoresButton;
private JButton afsluitenButton;

public HoofdmenuPaneel(Mainframe mainFrame){
    this.mainFrame = mainFrame;

    setLayout(null);

    setSize(330, 528);
    setLocation(461, 137);
    setBackground( new Color(255, 255, 255, 25) );

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == selecteerLevelButton)
    {
        System.out.println("selecteerLevelButton");
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == spelHervattenButton)
    {
        System.out.println("spelHervattenButton");
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == highscoresButton)
    {   
        this.hide();
        HighscoreInzien highscoreInzienTask = new HighscoreInzien(mainFrame);
        highscoreInzienTask.run();

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a variable called `mainFrame` inside your `HighscoreInzien` class.

Comment: Are all the classes compiled successfully? Is `HighscorePaneel` providing all the implementing  that is required .

Comment: aaaaaah, that makes sense! But it's in my main.. how do I link that to my main method? @ Braj, there are no other errors in my program, this is the only one. It also does exactly what i want it to do. i forgot to add a class where the run method from HighscoreInzien is called, but that works, so no need to post i guess.

Comment: Where is `HoofdmenuPaneel` class?

Comment: added it now, not complete, not useful to show all the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `Mainframe` object to `HighscoreInzien` class.

Do in this way:

```
public class HighscoreInzien {

    Mainframe mainFrame;

    public HighscoreInzien(Mainframe mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
    }

    ...
}

public class HoofdmenuPaneel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Mainframe mainFrame;
    public HoofdmenuPaneel(Mainframe mainFrame){
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        ...
    }
}

public class Mainframe extends JFrame   {

    public  Mainframe(){
       ...

       HoofdmenuPaneel hoofdmenuPaneel = new HoofdmenuPaneel(this);
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: this resolves the error in the `HighscoreInzien` class, but creates a new one in my `HoofdmenuPaneel`. It says that the constructor HighscoreInzien(), is undefined. I get that i will have to pass some args there. but i cant think of which, and how. is it Mainframe again?

Comment: Do it in the same manner for other classes also. Create a constructor in the same manner to pass `Mainframe`.

Comment: Even to the `Mainframe` itself? Because when i do that my main class gives an error. "The constructor Mainframe() is undefined " - ill edit the code above now to what i have atm

Comment: call `HoofdmenuPaneel hoofdmenuPaneel = new HoofdmenuPaneel(this);` in `Mainframe` class.

Comment: Do not do it for `Mainframe` class. Just do it for `HighscoreInzien` and `HoofdmenuPaneel`.

Comment: It worked! I got it :D Well, you got it. Can you explain the theory really short so I wont make this mistake again?

Comment: Its very simple. You have declared a local variable in some class and trying to access it in another class. You can't do in this way. You have to make it visible for others.

Comment: `Mainframe mainFrame = new Mainframe();` is a local variable that can be used inside `main` method only.

Comment: Ah you have made it so much clearer for me! Thank you. Last question and ill mark this as resolved. The `this` in `HoofdmenuPaneel hoofdmenuPaneel = new HoofdmenuPaneel(this);` says that i have to add it to the `Mainframe` right?

Comment: yes you are right. You are passing `Mainframe` object that is `this` here as you are calling it from inside `Mainframe` constructor.